# CakePHP testing model with fixture

Tags: testing, cakephp, phpunit, fixtures

I’ve been trying to make model tests with with fixtures, but I’m not able to load the records into the fixtures.

I’m using MySQL, I have a separate schema called `test_booking` which has empty tables corresponding to the production db. I’ve baked a fixture and model file with:

```
cake bake fixture Status
```

and

```
cake bake test table Status
```

which yielded the files below.

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Test\Fixture;

use Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\TestFixture;

/**
 * StatusFixture
 */
class StatusFixture extends TestFixture
{
    /**
     * Fields
     *
     * @var array
     */
    // phpcs:disable
    public $fields = [
        'id' => ['type' => 'integer', 'length' => null, 'unsigned' => false, 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'comment' => '', 'autoIncrement' => true, 'precision' => null],
        'type' => ['type' => 'string', 'length' => 45, 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'collate' => 'latin1_swedish_ci', 'comment' => '', 'precision' => null],
        'date' => ['type' => 'string', 'length' => 45, 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'collate' => 'latin1_swedish_ci', 'comment' => '', 'precision' => null],
        'start_time' => ['type' => 'string', 'length' => 5, 'null' => false, 'default' => '', 'collate' => 'latin1_swedish_ci', 'comment' => '', 'precision' => null],
        'service_id' => ['type' => 'integer', 'length' => null, 'unsigned' => false, 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'comment' => '', 'precision' => null, 'autoIncrement' => null],
        'date_created' => ['type' => 'timestamp', 'length' => null, 'precision' => null, 'null' => false, 'default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'comment' => ''],
        'date_modified' => ['type' => 'timestamp', 'length' => null, 'precision' => null, 'null' => false, 'default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'comment' => ''],
        'manned_by' => ['type' => 'integer', 'length' => null, 'unsigned' => false, 'null' => true, 'default' => null, 'comment' => '', 'precision' => null, 'autoIncrement' => null],
        'text' => ['type' => 'string', 'length' => 10000, 'null' => false, 'default' => '', 'collate' => 'latin1_swedish_ci', 'comment' => '', 'precision' => null],
        'active' => ['type' => 'boolean', 'length' => null, 'null' => false, 'default' => '1', 'comment' => '', 'precision' => null],
        '_constraints' => [
            'primary' => ['type' => 'primary', 'columns' => ['id'], 'length' => []],
        ],
        '_options' => [
            'engine' => 'InnoDB',
            'collation' => 'latin1_swedish_ci'
        ],
    ];
    // phpcs:enable
    /**
     * Init method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function init(): void
    {
        $this->records = [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'type' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                'date' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                'start_time' => 'Lor',
                'service_id' => 1,
                'date_created' => 1590634027,
                'date_modified' => 1590634027,
                'manned_by' => 1,
                'text' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                'active' => 1,
            ],
        ];
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table;

use App\Model\Table\StatusTable;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;

/**
 * App\Model\Table\StatusTable Test Case
 */
class StatusTableTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Test subject
     *
     * @var \App\Model\Table\StatusTable
     */
    protected $Status;

    /**
     * Fixtures
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fixtures = [
        'app.Status',
    ];

    /**
     * setUp method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $config = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->exists('Status') ? [] : ['className' => StatusTable::class];
        $this->Status = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Status', $config);
    }

    /**
     * tearDown method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function tearDown(): void
    {
        unset($this->Status);

        parent::tearDown();
    }

    /**
     * Test getStatus method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testGetStatus(): void
    {
        $status = $this->Status->getStatus(1);
        print_r($status);
        exit;
        $this->markTestIncomplete('Not implemented yet.');
    }
}
```

But running the tests which executes the testGetStatus() returns en empty array, instead of the record specified in the fixture. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit #1: phpunit.xml.dist:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    colors="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
    >
    <php>
        <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
        <ini name="apc.enable_cli" value="1"/>
    </php>

    <!-- Add any additional test suites you want to run here -->
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="app">
            <directory>tests/TestCase/</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <!-- Add plugin test suites here. -->
    </testsuites>

    <!-- Setup a listener for fixtures -->
    <listeners>
        <listener class="Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureInjector">
            <arguments>
                <object class="Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureManager"/>
            </arguments>
        </listener>
    </listeners>

    <!-- Ignore vendor tests in code coverage reports -->
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">src/</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">plugins/*/src/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <file>src/Console/Installer.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

**Edit #2: app_local.php:**

```php
    'Datasources' => [
        'default' => [
            'datasource' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'host' => '<ip prod>',
            'username' => 'xxx',
            'password' => 'xxx',
            'database' => 'booking',
            'schema' => 'booking',
        ],
        'test' => [
            'datasource' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'host' => '<ip stage>',
            'username' => 'xxx',
            'password' => 'xxx',
            'database' => 'test_booking',
            'schema' => 'test_booking',
        ],
    ],
```

**Edit #3: CLI command for running tests:**

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Comment: How are you running the tests (CLI command), and what does your `phpunit.xml` file look like?

Comment: Your naming is not valid for conventional approach. I wouldn't recommend this for beginners, as this can have pitfalls. The table should be `Statuses`, and thus also the fixture. The entity itself is called `Status` (singular) here only.
Just bake the whole thing and you avoid these issues: `bin/cake bake all Statuses` (it includes test case and fixture)

Comment: Unfortunely it's a lot of work to rename all the tables in the system at this point